# How to group records into matching pairs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to read data out of a SQL Server table that tracks Leaves of Absences. The data below represents how the data is pulled out of the table -- in theory an employee has an entry for when they go on leave and a second entry for when they return, and I can "pair" those two records together. Unfortunately there's nothing stopping users from entering multiple leave records without a return record, or a return record without a leave record.

I'm hoping somebody can show me a slick way to pair these records and mark/omit the records that do not pair using T-SQL.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #pmachist 
(
    pmah_eff_date smalldatetime, 
    pmah_emp int, 
    codeStatus varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #pmachist 
VALUES 
('20221012 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave'),
('20220908 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave'),
('20180509 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Return'),
('20180508 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave'),
('20180418 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Return'),
('20180417 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave'),
('20180327 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Return'),
('20180326 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave'),
('20180322 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Return'),
('20180320 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave'),
('20170307 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Return'),
('20170306 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave'),
('20140326 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Return'),
('20131209 00:00:00.000', 100028,   'Leave');
```

Comment: Will there ever be me more than one value of pmah_emp in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but perhaps the window function sum() over() may help

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Grp =sum( case when codeStatus = 'Return' then 1 end ) over (partition by pmah_emp order by pmah_eff_date desc)
 from #pmachist
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or data, please paste them in as text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @Charlieface In John's defense, an image as proof of a working answer doesn't cause many problems.

Comment: @Charlieface Nope.  It is a fast visual... that's all.   It does not need to be consumed in any fashion.